# multiplot in Rmisc package does not work in R?

Tags: r, plot

Can anybody help me on it? The following code works, but the two plots can not be shown in one image. There is no any error message. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
    library(Rmisc)
    require(latticeExtra)
    P1 <- with(group.UCL(weight~feed,chickwts,FUN=CI),
    segplot(feed~weight.lower+weight.upper,center=weight.mean))
    require(Hmisc)
    P2 <- with(group.UCL(Temp~Month,airquality,FUN=STDERR),
    xYplot(Cbind(Temp.mean,Temp.lower,Temp.upper)~numericScale(Month),
    type="b",ylim=c(60,90))
    multiplot(P1, P2, cols=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `multiplot` help says it's for use with `ggplot` objects. Your graphics are not `ggplot`s.

```
> class(P1)
[1] "trellis"
> class(P2)
[1] "trellis"
```

Maybe use `grid.arrange` instead?

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(P1, P2, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: The examples that I cited from the package (Rmisc): http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmisc/Rmisc.pdf. The author suggested to use multiplot for the figures from Rmisc.